# How to deploy Azure Functions Custom Handler for R langugage in Consumption Plan?

Tags: r, azure, azure-functions

First of all, let me say I am new to both R and Azure. I am trying to understand if I can run an R Custom Handler function in Azure on a Consumption Plan rather than Premium plan. For my use-case, I have no problem with cold-starts and won't need to scale for this workload. Also, I need to install a specific R package to expose as an API using this function.

From my online search I see that all R custom handlers examples resort to docker containers, which, from my understanding, need to be deployed under the premium plan.

Is it possible to run R custom handlers on a consumption plan considering the need to install packages? Is there any tutorial or sample code available that could get me started?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure-functions using custom-handler for R programming language in consumption based plan is not supported.

- Based on the Azure documentation , Azure functions using custom-handler for R programming you need to install the runtime or additional libraries as dependencies that require the use of a custom container.
- Deploying your function code in a custom container requires Premium plan or a Dedicated (App Service) plan hosting.

Here are the documented steps for  [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?pivots=programming-language-other&tabs=bash,portal) using customer handler  for R programming languages.